# LED blinking through Rpi Linux Device Driver

Tags: linux, driver, device

In device driver programming we are using 1. device driver code, 2. device file, 3. user space application code and 4. actual physical hardware.

- I am able to write the driver code, user space application code and manually creating device file but interfacing hardware i want to try (at least blinking an LED through device driver in Raspberry Pi) and it looks little difficult to me.
- And if I am able to blinking a LED means the communication is happening between all the above four listed items.

I was taken some online code for blinking LED and tested but its not working.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww i have posted the code below which learnt till today.

Answer (score 0):

```
Driver code:

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

#define BUF_MAX_SIZE 1024

int major_num;
char driver_buf[BUF_MAX_SIZE];

int myopen(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bhaskar: Open function called.\n");
    return 0;
}

int myclose(struct inode *indoep, struct file *filep)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bhaskar: Close function called.\n");
    return 0;
}

ssize_t myread(struct file *filep, char *ubuf, size_t nbytes, loff_t *offset)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bhaskar: Read function called.\n");
    copy_to_user(ubuf, driver_buf + filep->f_pos, nbytes);
    filep->f_pos += nbytes;
    return 0;
}

ssize_t mywrite(struct file *filep, const char *ubuf, size_t nbytes, loff_t *offset)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bhaskar: Write function called.\n");
    copy_from_user(driver_buf + filep->f_pos, ubuf, nbytes);
    filep->f_pos += nbytes;
    return 0;
}

loff_t mylseek(struct file *filep, loff_t offset, int whence)
{
    int newpos;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bhaskar: llseek function called.\n");
    switch(whence)
    {
        case SEEK_SET: 
            newpos = offset;
            printk(KERN_INFO "llseek called with SEEK_SET.\n");
            break;

        case SEEK_CUR:
            newpos = filep->f_pos + offset;
            printk(KERN_INFO "llseek called with SEEK_CUR.\n");
            break;

        case SEEK_END:
            newpos = BUF_MAX_SIZE + offset;
            printk(KERN_INFO "llseek called with SEEK_END.\n");
            break;
    }
    filep->f_pos = newpos;
    printk(KERN_INFO "new position of file pointer is:%d\n", newpos);
    return newpos;
}

struct file_operations fops = {
    .open = myopen,
    .release = myclose,
    .read = myread,
    .write = mywrite,
    .llseek = mylseek
};

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bhaskar: Module loaded successfully.\n");
    major_num = register_chrdev(0, "MyCharDriver", &fops);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Char driver registered with major num is:%d\n", major_num);
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bhaskar: Module unloaded successfully.\n");
    unregister_chrdev(major_num, "MyCharDriver");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Bhaskar <bhaskarauvsp@gmail.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Its a dummy char driver");

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Driver Application code:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[30];
    int fd, retread, retwrite, retlseek, retclose;

    fd = open("MyTestDevice", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    printf("Value of file descriptor:%d\n", fd);

    retwrite = write(fd, "welcome to embedded system", 27);
    printf("return value of write:%d\n", retwrite);

    retlseek = lseek(fd, 11, SEEK_SET);
    printf("return value of lseek:%d\n", retlseek);

    retread = read(fd, buf, 27);
    printf("return value of read:%d\n", retread);

    printf("Data read from driver is:%s\n", buf);

    retclose = close(fd);
    printf("return value of close:%d\n", retclose);

    return 0;
}
```

I am successfully able to communicate with application code from user space to driver in kernel space. And using this basic knowledge i want to blink LED and what are the things i need to learn after this program.